# how to increase size of text in web view

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

i have a web view and i want to increase size of text in it when i press button ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.zoom = '1.5';"]
```

This will zoom in all contents of the UIWebView by a factor 1.5.